# Reopen plugin model in main Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A plugin provides a model called `User`. Is it possible to reopen it in my app?

If I create `app/models/user.rb` and try it there, the whole model is overridden and the original plugin methods are no longer available.

Comment: How are you re-opening the User class? (in app/models/user.rb)

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` if I try `User.class_eval` then Rails says user.rb should define User.

Comment: By the way, I guess I could use `class_eval` from a file in the `lib` folder, but then I'd have to restart with every change, plus reopening it on app/models just feels right.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I found so far:

```
# app/models/plugin_user.rb
class PluginUser
  def self.load
    User.class_eval do
      # my code here
    end
  end
end

# plugin model:
class User
  # ...
end

PluginUser.load
```

It would be nice if there was a way of doing this without modifying the plugin code. In this case it doesn't matter because the plugin is mine, but if I needed to do the same to another plugin I'd need to fork it.